# Generating tiles from matplotlib plots

Tags: python, leaflet, tiles, matplotlib

I have a number of analyses that are being plotted as heat maps in UTM coordinates using matplotlib. I'd like to generate tiles from these to display on a leaflet map over top of an OSM map.

At this point, the only thoughts I have are to either plot multiple plots using matplotlib where the extent matches the tile, or alternatively, generate one large plot, georeference it and use tiling software to slice it up.

Is there a simpler solution to this problem that I'm missing?

Is there a better way to do this than using matplotlib?

Comment: don't know with matpotlib, but tiling is quite usual thing to do with GIS software (like QGIS) and map Server or generate tiles with GDAL [gdal2tiles](http://gdal.gloobe.org/gdal/gdal2tiles.html) and convert to mbtiles [mbutil](https://github.com/Outdooractive/mbutil)